# Balanced three phase circuit Y-Y with neutral

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits

Here is my equivalent balanced three phase circuit Y-Y with neutral:

[image]

**Rla + jXla** is my line impedance by phase. **L1** and **L2** are my loads.
The exercise is saying that **L1** absorbs **180 W** and **240 VAr**, **L2** absorbs **600 VAr** and has **0.6 lagging power factor**. The line impedance is **5 + j8**. The line voltage is **240 V**. Its asking me what is the voltage **VAN** across the loads.

LOOK WHAT I HAVE TRIED:

```
VAN.IL1* = SL1 = 180 + j240 VA
VAN.IL2* = SL2 = 450 + j600 VA
VAN.IL* = SL = SL1 + SL2 = 630 + j840 VA
IL = IL1 + IL2
VaA = IL.(Ra+jXLa)
VAN = Van - VaA
Van = 240/sqrt(3) with angle of -30 degrees
SL/IL* = Van - IL.(Ra+jXLa)
(630 + j840)/IL* = (120 - j69.282) - IL(5 + j8)
```

When I throw this equation at wolfram alpha, It says there's no solution:

[Link for wolfram alpha's analysis](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28630.0%20%2b%20i*840.0%29/conjugate%28z%29%20=%20%28120.0%20-%20i*69.282%29%20-%20z*%285.0%20%2b%20i*8.0%29)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't have time to go through this fully, but the Alpha analysis says there is no solution *assuming* $z>0$*(i.e. $z$ is real). It doesn't actually say there is no solution. You're looking for complex solutions

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No and I've never tried again...